# Create SFDX Project - 'npm' error

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, error

I have historically been able to create SFDX projects with no issue but have just began to receive the following error on creation:

```
Starting SFDX: Create Project

16:16:37.144 sfdx force:project:create --projectname HelperJS --outputdir c:\Users\mhandler\Desktop --template standard
ERROR running force:project:create:  Command failed with exit code 1: npm root -g --prefix c:\Users\mhandler\Desktop\.yo-repository --loglevel error
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
16:16:43.741 sfdx force:project:create --projectname HelperJS --outputdir c:\Users\mhandler\Desktop --template standard
 ended with exit code 1
```

Steps to Replicate:

1. SFDX: Create Project
2. 'Standard'
3. ProjectName: 'HelperJS'
4. Tried Multiple Folders Including Desktop & Sub-folders

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am unable to create an SFDX Projects now.

Thanks,

Comment: @sfdcfox yep, that worked. Had to install Node and restart and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install NPM

https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/

Once is installed, if needed probably add the npm folder to the $path or env variables , depending on your OS. Just follow the tutorial.